No module named 'matplotlib' even after installing matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

# Number of apples eaten each day
apples_eaten = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1]

# Create a line chart
plt.plot(days, apples_eaten)

# Add a title
plt.title('Apples Eaten Per Day')

# Label the x-axis
plt.xlabel('Day')

# Label the y-axis
plt.ylabel('Apples Eaten')

# Show the plot
plt.show()


I just want to run this simple code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\test_\hi.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

I researched a bit about it and Some people say Create a virtual Env i did create a virtual env still This is showing..Help
I Expected to see a graph when i run the code

Try python -m pip list calling python in the same way you did for running the script and see if matplotlib is contained in pip's output.

#!/usr/bin/env python
